# Unable to convert this JSON to a string

Tags: ios, json, swift3, xcode8

```
 Please see below the json output

 {
     "queryLogs" : [
     {
       "status" : "false",
      "query" : {
        "contents" : {
          "updated" : "",
          "id" : 1488199579,
          "created" : "",
          "patient_count" : 60,
          "isactive" : "1",
          "status_id" : 0,
          "starttime" : "",
          "queue_status_id" : 0,
          "date_consult" : ""
        },
        "conditions" : "{}"
      },
      "tableName" : "consultation",
      "type" : "I",
      "logId" : {
        "id" : "261489537666",
        "doctorId" : "100"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

Need to convert above json into below format

```
 {"queryLogs":[{ "logId":{"id":"76148951287","doctorId":"100"},
    "tableName":"queue", "type":"I", "query":"{ \"contents\":{  
    \"patient_name\":\"queryLog Test\", \"status_id\":1, 
    \"queue_no\":\"6\",       \"isactive\":1, \"id\":\"148956612\", 
    \"mobile\":\"9567969610\",       \"updated\":\"2017-03-15 11:31:26 
    GMT+05:30\", \"created\":\"2017-03-15      11:31:26 GMT+05:30\", 
    \"consultation_id\":\"1495085636\"},     \"conditions\":{} 
    }","status":"false"}]}
```

First code is what i get when i convert the JSON, But how can i get the JSON like the second code.
i used below code to get the first output.

```
  var f = ["queryLogs":[["status":"false","tableName":"consultation","type":"I","logId":ids,"query":logfile]]] as [String : Any]
 let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: f,     
    options:.prettyPrinted)
        if let content = String(data: JSON!, encoding: 
    String.Encoding.utf8) {

           print(content)
    }
```

Comment: Show the initialization of f

Comment: f is a [string:Any] dictionary

Comment: Add that in your question with its value

Comment: var f = ["queryLogs":[["status":"false","tableName":"consultation","type":"I","logId":ids,"query":logfile]]] as [String : Any]

Comment: what? sorry mate you didnt get my question.

Comment: I have to make a JSON string as shown in the second code. with backslash inside the "query" object.

Comment: @NiravD thiese are the dictionaries used.                                                               var lg = ["status_id":con.status_id,"queue_status_id":con.queue_status_id,"isactive":"1","id":con.id,"starttime":con.starttime,"date_consult":checkstrg,"updated":checkstrg,"patient_count":con.patient_count,"created":checkstrg] as! [String : Any]
        var logfile = ["contents":lg , "conditions":"{}"] as! [String : Any].              var f = ["queryLogs":[["status":"false","tableName":"consultation","type":"I","logId":ids,"query":logfile]]] as [String : Any]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want response like that then you need to also make `JSON` string for your `logfile` dictionary also.

What you can do is make one `extension` of `Dictionary`, so that no need to write same code of `JSONSerialization` at every place.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var jsonString: String? {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self),
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                return nil
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

Now use this extension to get `JSON` string from your dictionaries.

```
let id‌​s = ["id" : "261489537666", "doctorId" : "100"]
let  logfile =   [
        "contents" : [
            "updated" : "",
            "id" : 1488199579,
            "created" : "",
            "patient_count" : 60,
            "isactive" : "1",
            "status_id" : 0,
            "starttime" : "",
            "queue_status_id" : 0,
            "date_consult" : ""
        ],
        "conditions" : "{}"
] as [String : Any]

if let queryLogString = logfile.jsonString {
    let f = ["queryLogs":[["status":"false","tableName":"consultation","‌​type":"I","logId": id‌​s,"query":queryLogString]]] as [String : Any]
    if let content = f.jsonString {
        print(content)

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"queryLogs":[{"status":"false","query":"{\"contents\":{\"updated\":\"\",\"id\":1488199579,\"created\":\"\",\"patient_count\":60,\"isactive\":\"1\",\"status_id\":0,\"starttime\":\"\",\"queue_status_id\":0,\"date_consult\":\"\"},\"conditions\":\"{}\"}","tableName":"consultation","‌​type":"I","logId":{"id":"261489537666","doctorId":"100"}}]}
```

Comment: Thnak you so much mate. you are a genius

Comment: @faheem Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

once try like,

```
  let data  = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    if let content = String(data: data!, encoding:
        String.Encoding.utf8) {

        print(content)
    }
```

Comment: this is the output  when i get for your method. Still im not getting the backslash inside the query field contents.                                  {"queryLogs":[{"status":"false","query":{"contents":{"updated":"","id":1488199579,"created":"","patient_count":60,"isactive":"1","status_id":0,"starttime":"","queue_status_id":0,"date_consult":""},"conditions":"{}"},"tableName":"consultation","type":"I","logId":{"id":"261489537666","doctorId":"100"}}]}